# How to normalize category database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got a MySQL DB with ~5000 rows. It occurred to me that before adding anymore records or columns I need to get the database normalized. But even with all the research I've done I'm struggling to understand several concepts. Here is an example of my existing database schema.

```
PK Category1 Category2 Category3 Produce_String   Keywords       Zip State City Country
1  Vegetable Potato              f5kkfid34fbn     organic        ... ..... ...  .....
2  Vegetable Potato              plf85jfuvj       organic,fresh  ... ..... ...  .....
3  Vegetable Cherry    Tomato    jf9vmu37jg9      fresh        
4  Fruit     Lemon               kfkt8hkf0e       fresh,yellow
5  Fruit     Lemon               fkg8rr03gnf       
6  Fruit     Red       Apple     fkf9gkty367r6    crispy
```

My main misunderstanding, is how to relate the data to one another once the columns are separated into individual tables? For example, in a DB client I can see the rows and how they relate to one another, but if I separate them this will no longer be the case. I am also concerned with having to update multiple tables for the same record but I suppose this is unavoidable.
Also, I'm not clear on the proper way to normalize this. My mind tells me to only separate the Keywords column since it's the only column that has comma separated entries. But by normalization standards I believe I need to separate the categories, keywords, and location.

**EDIT**
Another concern I have, is that if I put the categories in a separate table, each with their own row, I lose the structure. So I lose the ability to sort by the specific categories. For example, the vegetable category would not be related to a fruit. Since the Produce_String is unique, could I use it as the foreign key in the other tables?

Comment: This is more of a question if you want to learn the discipline of formal database design or if you want to do by your own you think is correct. Learning the discipline of database design and technologies that are related to it, is painful early on but worth it. Your design serves you for the moment but it would eventually cost you in terms of maintenance later on.

Comment: Someone please put this question out of its misery and vote to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have separate `Category` and `Keywords` tables

```
category                           keyword
-------------------------          -------------------------
    id      | name                     id    | name
     1      | Vegetable                 1    | organic
     2      | Potato                    2    | fresh
```

Than make two additional tables for `MANY TO MANY` relations:

```
category_to_product                keyword_to_product
-------------------------          -------------------------
category_id | product_id           keyword_id | product_id
     1      |     1                    1      |     1
     1      |     2                    1      |     2
     2      |     1                    2      |     2
```

And to update categories for product #1:

```
DELETE * FROM `category_to_product` WHERE `product_id` = :product_id;
INSERT INTO `category_to_product` (`category_id`, `product_id`) VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (8, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It just seems like a mess to manage. I'd much rather keep a string as a reference rather than relating everything with an integer.

Comment: @EternalHour Don't use string as key. It will be very slow. Use ID's as much as possible. And your category name can change at any given time, so you will have to update all relevant tables, where you use category name as key, too. It's bad!

Answer (score 0):

This is a question with a potentially long answer, and you might be better off starting with somewhere like [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) or similar. But in a nutshell:

Normalisation usually solves more problems than it causes. Consider someone who spelt "Vegetable" as "Vegteable" for one of the rows in your example, or consider if you wanted to add a fourth category. Or what about if you wanted to change all instances of the category "Baby Marrow" to "Zuccini". You are correct that both of these could be implemented as separate tables.

One of the criteria that you can use for deciding whether to normalise or not is to think about where you want to control the integrity of the data. You may be in control of application code now, that ensures that the category names are always used consistently, but it's hard to foresee what applications will come in the future. Keeping the list of categories in it's own table makes sure that when you link two products to the same category, they are indeed linked to the same category (i.e. the single row "Vegetable" in the category table). When you change a category, you can change it in one place. You can easily find all products linked to a single category before you delete a category, and so on.

Yes, once the data is in separate tables, you don't see it all in one row any longer, but joining the data is what relational data is all about, and you can probably use database views to recreate the layout that you've shown us from the underlying normalised data. It is very normal to join several tables in an SQL select statement.

Comment: I can definitely see the advantage, but my concern is manageability. If possible I'd like to keep my queries based on words rather than id's.

Comment: So you are talking about the difference between `select * from product where category1="Vegetable" or category2="Vegetable" or category3="Vegetable"` and `select * from product p, productCategory pc, category c where pc.forProduct=p.d and pc.forCategory=c.id and c.name="Vegetable"`. You get used to it, and there are a lot of advantages!

Comment: Think about it this way, with three category columns, you have 3 strings to manage - i would find that very messy :)